# How to avoid "too many redirects" with NGINX

Tags: nginx

Here is the rewrite I added and when I visit `/name` I have an infinite loop of redirects.

```
rewrite ^/name /name-and-more permanent;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rewrite `^/name` to `/name-and-more` which results in a 301 redirect.

Then next request is for `/name-and-more` which matches the same rewrite `^/name`, so it redirects again to `/name-and-more`, and again etc..

You have missed the trailing `$` so that it matches exact URL `/name`.

So:

```
rewrite ^/name$ /name-and-more permanent;
```